# Why javascript removes whitespace in String

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make hangman game and I want to display on the screen password like  '_ _ _[space]  _ _[space] _ _ _ _ _' . When I look at the variable it looks fine but it is instered into html without any space, what makes this application useless. Could you please help what should I change to see expected result? Thanks in advance
[image]

```
function hideWord() {
var password = '';
for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) === ' ')
        password += '  ';
    else password += '_';
    password += ' '
}
setHiddenWord(password);
}

function setHiddenWord(password) {
    document.querySelector('div.letters').innerHTML += password;
}
```

Comment: try replacing " " (space) with "&nbsp;"

Comment: JavaScript does not remove it. HTML rendering is removing it.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is not removing the whitespace - The browser rendering of the HTML is. By default, HTML does not respect white space. If you want it to, put a `white-space: pre;` or `white-space: pre-wrap;` style on your element

In your CSS:

```
div.letters {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: To be a bit more clear, the HTML parser in the browser is removing all but one space ("normalizing" the content) when the `.innerHTML` method of the DOM object is set. The "browser" is also responsible for hosting the JS runtime environment, so it actually is correct to say that the browser is doing it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, that's exactly right, thank you for the clarification, Scott!